# Cannot read property Ionic3

Tags: ionic3

I'm having problems when it comes to getting data from a service. I enter the application and I miss an error like "Can not read property X, it does not exist". Then I modify anything in my document, and then I modify it again to leave it as before, and finally it works without problems with Ionic serve. If I try to create the build it keeps giving me the previous error

Can someone help me?

```
let url= URL_SERVICES + "/EspacioProtegidoMapa";
let body=new HttpParams().set('ID', id);
this.http.post(url,body).subscribe(resp=>{  
  if ((resp['_code'] == 200) && (resp.hasOwnProperty('_result'))) {
  console.log("RESP"+resp._result);
  var featureCollection = resp._result[0];
  console.log(featureCollection)
  var features = featureCollection.features[1];
  var title = resp['_msg'];
  console.log(resp['_code']);
```

In resp._result[0] It's the error

Comment: Hey which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, I was finally able to solve the problem, I had to define some interfaces to define the data I was taking from the service